# How to delete after last marker without pausing the recording?

Tags: recording, software, adobe-audition

I'm recording a voiceover for a slide show in an Adobe Audition multi-track session. For each slide, I often need multiple attempts to get a good take.

To mark the boundaries between slides and parts of the recording I want to keep or discard later, I insert markers via <kbd>m</kbd> throughout the recording. However, later I have to listen to the marked sections again to tell which of them I wanted to keep or discard.

- Is there a way while recording to directly delete everything since the last marker without pausing the recording?
- Or is there a way to insert markers of different colors using a keyboard shortcut so I can later see which sections I want to keep or discard?
- Or is there another solution to this problem that can speed up the workflow?

Comment: I don't know Audition at all, but will it not cycle record, so each take gets dropped to a new track? That's normally how you'd comp vocals or voice-over.

Comment: @Tetsujin I can manually switch tracks between takes but it takes several keystrokes to stop the recording, reset the playhead, change tracks, and start a new recording. I was hoping there would be a solution that lets me mark/remove outtakes with a single keystroke without pausing the recording.

Comment: I found a ream of people moaning that it can't do that - https://adobe-video.uservoice.com/forums/911314-audition/suggestions/34912825-feature-request-adr-tools - which I guess means you'd have to use one of the editors that can. Cubase/Nuendo Logic, ProTools & apparently DaVinci can all do this.